# How to pass objects correctly between java and android using Sockets TCP?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send an object using TCP/IP using an Android application an a Java application.
But I'm having the problem that the information coming is null.

The object belongs to a class called Mensaje, and in both projects has the same package name and have the same serialVersionUID:

```
package CLASSESS;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Mensaje implements Serializable{
   // private static final long serialVersionUID = 5950169519310163575L;
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 9178463713495656548L;
    public static int TYPE;
    public static int ID;
    public static String DATA;
}
```

The Android application class implements Serializable and handles the conexion into a Threat

```
public class SocketClient implements Serializable{



private Runnable send_ObjectMessage = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            try {
                obj_Mensaje = new Mensaje();
                obj_Mensaje.TYPE = 1;
                obj_Mensaje.ID = 2;
                obj_Mensaje.DATA= "hOKA MUNDO";
                salida_mensaje = new ObjectOutputStream(socket_cliente.getOutputStream());
                salida_mensaje.writeObject(obj_Mensaje);
                salida_mensaje.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
}
```

The Server has the same Mensaje class  and implements Serializable with the same serialVersionUID;

The server reads the object on a Threat.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        obj_message_read = new Mensaje();
        ois_readMessage = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        while(clientSocket.isConnected()){
            Object aux = ois_readMessage.readObject();
            if(aux instanceof Mensaje){
                obj_message_read = (Mensaje)aux;
                setDATA(obj_message_read.DATA);
                setTYPE(obj_message_read.TYPE);
                setID(obj_message_read.ID);
                System.out.println("Data" + obj_message_read.DATA);

            }
        }
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The problem is that the information coming in the Mensaje is null. 
So when i print  `System.out.println("Data" + obj_message_read.DATA);`
the Server prints

> Data Null

Comment: Don't use Java serialization to "send" objects between endpoints. Protocols/data formats are aplenty which are platform independent, use those instead. JSON, for instance. Or protobuf. Or... Or... Or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the fields you are trying to send are declared as `static`, which are transient for serialization.

Change it removing that keyword:

```java
public class Mensaje implements Serializable{
   // private static final long serialVersionUID = 5950169519310163575L;
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 9178463713495656548L;
    public int TYPE;
    public int ID;
    public String DATA;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, You´re right. It´s strange because i used the same project like 3 years ago and it worked fine.

Comment: What do you mean with "which are transient for serialization"?

Comment: It means that they are ignored.

Comment: @mavi No you didn't. This code never worked at all. Static fields have never been serialized, and a class with only static data is almost always a major design mistake unless it is a singleton.

Comment: Hi @EJP, thanks for you answer, if coding with static files is a mistake, how would you manage global variables for you entire application? because i usually use a global class for manage globla variables. Thanks